# Javascript/PHP %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S adjust for the local computer time

Tags: php, javascript, unix-timestamp

I have time data in mySQL in the format of %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S as UTC +0 format.
And I want to display the time data adjusting for the local computer tha user is using.

For example:
The data is 2012-05-29 15:00:00
Then the time should be shown to a user in East time 2012-05-29 11:00:00 (applying daylightsaving, UTC -4hour)
and for the westcoast should displayed 2012-05-20 08:00:00 (URC -7hour)

Any scripts for converting this? either PHP or Javascript is good.Thanks!

Comment: You need JS for this, PHP runs on the server, and knows nothing about the client.

Comment: Never trust local computer time.

Comment: What do you mean that never trust local computer time???

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: @clerksx: computer users are notorious for not setting things up properly, so there's no guarantee AT ALL that the user's system clock, let alone time zone settings, are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Store all your dates internally using UTC and then for each user set:

```
if ( $_SESSION['user_timezone'] ) date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['user_timezone']);
```

If you want to be brave and your users are internet based (as opposed to using VPN like most of mine) you can lookup their location using location services.

I store this per user and just let them pick.

Easy way to generate the timezone list to present to the user:

```
echo '<select id="userTimezone" onChange="some_ajax_function">
        <option value="">Please select your Timezone</option>';
foreach (DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $value )
{
    if ( $_SESSION['user_timezone'] == $value )
    {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $value . '" selected="selected">' . htmlentities($value) . '</option>';
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $value . '">' . htmlentities($value) . '</option>';
    }
}
$output .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example using PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) class.

```
$time = '2012-05-29 15:00:00';

$datetime = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2012-05-29 08:00:00
```

[Date and Time Classes](http://php.net/datetime)

Comment: What was the result?  Are you using PHP 5.2 or greater?